# Microsoft Word Mail Merge - Percentage format when cell contains both percent and text

Tags: ms-word, mailmerge

I am performing a mail merge and have an issue when trying to correct the percentage format. The problem is that the source column contains both a percent value and text. If I map the field, percents display as decimal in word. If I use the following, it displays correctly:

{=«Percent»*100 # 0%}

However, now when the row contains text I receive an error.

Is there another way I can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the formula you need

{={MERGEFIELD XYZ}*100\ #0.00%}

Answer (score 0):

No, Word has no way to do string manipulation in its fields. Add another field / column to your data source for the text, or format the percentile in Excel before performing the merge.